# Integration of WSO2 Governance Registry with WSO2 Data Analytic Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, wso2-governance-registry

How can integration of WSO2 Governance Registry can be done with WSO2 Data Analytic Server? There seems to be no information about the integration of the two though WSO2 talks of it.

Comment: Please share the proposed architectural diagram to answer this question?

Comment: @thusharaK Actually I am just trying to explore the various capabilities of the WSO2 products and just like Integration of GReg and API-M is possible, I would like to explore and publish some data from GReg onto DAS and GReg says that the integration is possible but does not provide information on how.

Comment: Yes, Integration is possible. To provider proper answer I need to know you use-cases and architectural diagram if have any? Please feel free to provide them.

Comment: @thusharaK Consider a use case like I want to integrate GREG with DAS to see how many times a specific endpoint is being accessed and show it to the internal business to realize how useful an API is. I don't have an architectural diagram because its just a plain internal POC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Governance Registry, we only store the metadata of the endpoints. We cannot access the endpoints through Governance Registry. We need to have either WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus or WSO2 API Manager to control access to specific endpoints.

If you need to get accessed stats of an API, you can have WSO2 API Manager and WSO2 Data Analytic Server integration as [[1]](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics+Using+RDBMS)

1. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics+Using+RDBMS